# Unity Build error/path access denied issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Lately, for me, Unity started to act a bit weird. After working on my first project for several weeks, I wanted to create my first build and I did - it went smoothly, everything rendered just fine, etc.

After this success I realized I need to add 2 minor things to my project and I did - but since then my building thing is keep crashing after a few seconds.

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2816 ms)

Building Player failed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

For a brief moment, I thought I fixed it - I updated my Unity editor to the latest version, re-added my project to Unity Hub, and my projected build successfully...but just one. Now the builder is keep crashing. Has anyone encountered this before?

Also, while trying to find a fix for this I realized that I can't reset my Unity Layout - I keep getting this weird error (restarted Unity, PC, updated the Editor, etc):

```
OException: Access to the path '\\?\D:\Unity\xxxxx\UserSettings\Layouts' is denied.

System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryInternal (System.String fullPath, System.Boolean topLevel,
```

Any idea what can cause this? Could this access issue crash my build process as well?

Thanks in advance!

To be honest I am not sure what are the causes for the issues above so I did the basic - restarted unity, updated the Editor, restarted PC, cleared cache.

The only thing that made my unity build my project for the second time was updating the editor but now it crashes again.

I am really curious if the access thing is one of the issues for the builder.

Comment: In general: use a proper version control (e.g. GIT) -> simply restore a previous state or check exactly what was changed between two "commits" in order to avoid this kind of trouble in the future

Comment: layouts shouldnt effect a build as runtime doesnt care how yur ide looks.  what was the detail of the buidl error? things that can cause denied, actual access rights, av haviung it open, onedrive replicating it, google drive replicating it.. etc

Comment: @BugFinder Actually my project is constantly synced by google drive. I just created a new project, a blank one and I moved the files from my actual project in the blank one. No more denied errors. The moment I synced my new working project with my drive...the error appeared again, so you were right, google drive is actually interfering with my path accesses if I understand this correctly

Comment: @BugFinder Regarding the build issues, not sure how to catch the actual error that causes this :( . Sometimes the build crashes after 2 seconds, other times after 12, 27 seconds

Comment: well build failed shows the console the bottom of the consoler shows the details.  you can also check the log files frm your unity ide

Comment: This is all I get from my Unity console: ```Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2816 ms)

Building Player failed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)``

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed my issues. It seems Google Drive was messing with file permissions so both path access and Unity builder were acting weird.

I uninstalled Google Drive and made a fresh new project using the backup files from my project. Everything is working just fine now, without any issues.

Now I am using Github as my backup solution.